# Custom Object missing from English translation in Translation Workbench but not other languages

Tags: related-list, translation, translation-workbench

I'm trying to rename a managed package custom object's related list label through the Translation workbench using [this article](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000004527&language=en_US) as a guide.

When selecting "English" as the language and the Setup Component as "Custom Field", my custom object, **Payment Type**, does not appear in the Object dropdown.

[image: English translation]

[image]

When I change the language to Spanish, however, it does.

[image]

[image]

The object is in a master-detail relationship which may be relevant.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For custom objects that are part of a Managed Package this is done slightly different, because you have to override the values provided in the package:

1. Click Setup->Translation Workbench->Override
2. In the override screen, select the Managed Package that contains the field
   you want to relabel
3. Pick the Component that you want to relabel (in this case, Custom Field)
4. Pick the object that contains the field
5. Pick "Field Label" (or whichever aspect you want to override)
6. The rest is same as 'normal' fields

The reason that you only have to do this for 'English' is that the Managed Package's language is probably English and thus they have provided only the labels for that 1 language. So only 1 set of labels to override.

Comment: Thanks @Guy. One change though - as I was looking for the related list label  - so the option I would choose for Aspect is "Related List Label".