# Translation Workbench Override Managed Package Custom Field Label

Tags: managed-package, metadata, translation-workbench

Following the instructions from the answer [Custom Object missing from English translation in Translation Workbench but not other languages](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/126985/custom-object-missing-from-english-translation-in-translation-workbench-but-not), I've overridden a custom field label of managed package.

To retrieve the same using ANT, I've the below package.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>CustomApplication</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>CustomObject</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>CustomPageWebLink</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>CustomTab</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>ReportType</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
       <name>Scontrol</name>
    </types>
    <types>
       <members>*</members>
        <name>Translations</name>
    </types>
    <version>39.0</version>
</Package>
```

The translation folder has en_US.translation file and labels folder has  CustomLabels.labels file. The former lists the custom field in there

```
<customLabels>
        <label><!-- Identity_Type --></label>
        <name>MYORG__Identity_Type</name>
   </customLabels>
```

However I cannot find the label in CustomLabels.labels file. Neither any files in folders that was retrieved.

What need to be done to retrieve the overridden label to code repository. Am I missing some steps?

Answer (score 2):

Managed package field label override is done by Translation workbench. It's not custom labels.

For deployment to other sandbox org, we followed the following step

1. Go to Setup>Translation Workbench>Export
2. Choose option "Bilingual"

The exported file contained two section# TRANSLATED and UNTRANSLATED. Manually deleted the UNTRANSLATED section.

3. In other sandbox org, imported the translation file using Setup>Translation Workbench>Import

I wished this is supported by metadata or tooling api. Please post if you find other way of doing it.

Comment: We are doing exactly the same for translation overrides migration. But encountered with the problem that such overrides are not returned by Metadata API retrieve call at subscribers org level(